# Error in saving record into MS Access database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have got couple of errors in my code in VB and I cant figure out how do I solve it.

**First error** is in the following part says 
`value cannot be null parameter name: data table`

```
da.Fill(dt, "ORDER")
    Con.Close()
```

The **Second Error** is in this part:

```
 dsNewRow = ds.Tables(0).NewRow()
```

And here is the whole code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source=C:\Users\pao\Desktop\Projecto1.accdb"
    Con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    Con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT *FROM ORDER"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Con)
    da.Fill(dt, "ORDER")
    Con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If name_.TextLength > 0 And address_.TextLength > 0 And key.TextLength > 0 Then
        Dim pizzaArr() = pizza.ToArray()
        Dim spagArr() = spaghetti.ToArray()
        Dim grindersArr() = grinders.ToArray()
        Dim dsNewRow As  DataRow
        For Each element As String In grindersArr
            MsgBox(element)
        Next

        dsNewRow = ds.Tables(0).NewRow()
        dsNewRow.Item(0) = key.Text
        dsNewRow.Item(1) = name_.Text
        dsNewRow.Item(2) = address_.Text
        ds.Tables("ORDER").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
        da.Update(ds, "ORDER")
        MsgBox("ORDER ADDED", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "record")
        maxrows = ds.Tables("ORDER").Rows.Count
        ''
    Else
        MsgBox("COMPLETE THE FORM!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "INCOMPLETE!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '' Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    '' Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

    ''    dsNewRow = ds.Tables("form").NewRow()
    ''  dsNewRow.Item(0) = key.Text
    ''   dsNewRow.Item(1) = name_.Text
    ''   dsNewRow.Item(2) = address_.Text

    ''   ds.Tables("form").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

    MsgBox("RECORD ADDED", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "record")
    MaxRows = ds.Tables("form").Rows.Count 

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see your declaration for `dt`.  Make sure to add the word `new` in front of it.

Comment: what do you mean sir? is it like this? da.Fill(New DataTable, "ORDER") or da.Fill(New Dt, "ORDER") ?

Comment: No, I'm guessing you have a line in your code: `Dim dt As DataTable`.  Change it to `Dim dt As New DataTable`.  Otherwise, `ORDER` is a key word and should be in brackets `[ORDER]`.  If not too late, I would change the name of that table to something else.  This is obviously not VB6.

Comment: right I get it. now i got another error i changed the table name and now its  da.Fill(dt, "tableto")
        Con.Close()  
and gives me error
Object is not an ADODB.RecordSet or an ADODB.Record.
Parameter name: adodb

Comment: I don't see any parameter `adodb`! In .NET you would use `OleDb` anyway, not ADODB. ADODB is VB6.

Comment: but I am using oledb :/

Comment: what exactly the solution for that line